# What are the solfege syllables?

Tags: sheet-music, ear-training, sight-reading, solfege

Are they C,D,E,F,G,A or do re me fa so la to do? I have an online assignment due and my classmates say it’s CDEFGA but I’m confused.

Answer (score 1):

Solfege *represents* those letter names, therefore - do re me fa so la ti (or si) are solfege for C D E F G A and B. This is in what's known as *fixed doh* There is another similar system which calls the root note of *any* key doh. So it's confusing. This isn't a 'do your homework for you' site, though!